# How can I display user's documents (pdf) to them on a website?

Tags: web-development

As the title suggests, I need to create a document viewer such that a user can log into our website and view the files tied to their account.

The reason I'm struggling with this is that the files are stored in Google Drive and contain sensitive data so must be kept private. Moreover, the users have accounts and login details already so requiring them to sign up with a google account is not an option. As far as I'm aware, this rules out trying to display them directly from google drive. I have considered temporarily moving them (just while user is logged in) to Google Cloud Platform where we have a storage bucket hosting the website however, there is a lot of files to move and I can't find a way to do that programmatically (using Colaboratory I can move multiple files, but not automatically like when a new user registers for example).

I'm hoping there's an obvious solution to this that I've overlooked but any solution would do at this point. Thanks.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354325/how-can-i-display-users-documents-pdf-to-them-on-a-website "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat Sorry, I've deleted the old question now

Comment: Also, why Google Drive?

Comment: @user253751 That's just what my organisation chose to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an obvious solution you've overlooked.

When the server gets a request for a file, it gets the file from Google Drive, then sends the file as the response. Exactly the same as it would work if the file was on the filesystem, or in a database, or anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't get the file from Google Drive without being required to sign in to Google. Unless I make the folder viewable to anyone with the link. If it was as simple as sending a request for the file then surely anybody would be able to view it?

Comment: @Updog well then your server needs to sign in to Google

Comment: Do you know if I can do this with a Service Account? It looks like I can allow users to view data from Google Drive by authorising them as the service account(using the 'Enable GSuite Domain-Wide Delegation' option). I'm currently looking into this but there's an awful lot to read